# Phone Number in Wordpress Menu

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

My site is: http://design.budapestlooks.hu (currently using a subdomain until the site is finished)

I am using a theme called themify ultra, and there is no option to place a phone number on the very right side of the menu, unless I make a button for it.

I tried creating a menu button, and setting it to float: right; but it wouldn't work, and unfortunately, I'm not a PHP savvy!

Could you please recommend me something?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom link inside your menu, with the url `tel://your_number`.

Comment: Thank you very much, i happen to know this, but i would like to place it apart from my menu on the right side, and haven't seen an option to do this!

Comment: You can give it a special class and then you have to style it like you want?

Comment: @ArpadBalogh Good, don't forget to resolve your question.

Comment: Sure thing!  I got it working with position:relative; and positioning it, but now when i try to lower the size of my browser window, it flows out of the screen, so it cuts out a certain part of the text.  Do you know maybe, how can i fix that? Thank you very much again!

Comment: @ArpadBalogh You must to add a media query to fix that. `@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    // some properties here
}`

Comment: I have tried inserting this into my Custom CSS, but it's not working :(

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) { 

.telephone { display: none; }  

}

.telephone is the custom class of the menu button

Comment: @ArpadBalogh Try to add this `display: none !important;`

Comment: It is working now thank you, i just had to set the max-width number to 1500! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Adding a clickable phone number to the **WordPress** menu bar is simple a matter of prefixing the phone number with `tel:` which indicates to the web browser that the number following is a phone number.

**For example**

```
tel:0249501140
```

The link on the menu bar in WordPress can be text or the **phone number**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, i happen to know this, but i would like to place it apart from my menu on the right side, and haven't seen an option to do this!